# Alternative for regex lookbehind not supported on FF and IE

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

I'm trying to extract a string from an url.
I'm using vuejs but the router cannot be used as the page is a callback url returned by AWS Cognito OIDC signin.

The url looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/callback#id_token=eyJ...&access_token=eyJ...&expires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer&state=xxx
```

This is fine if there's a solution for vue router to handle the hash sign so that I can use:

```
this.$route.query.id_token
```

For the moment I retrieve the token using:

```
const matches = this.url.match(/(?<==).*(?=&acc)/i);
```

Which is only supported by Chrome. It retrieves anything bewteen the '=' char and the string '&acc'.
For what I want to do the id_token or the access_token are equivalent.

How can I get a token string without lookbehind ?

Comment: This might help. [`id_token=(.*?)&`](https://regex101.com/r/11HFUh/9)Or you could append `acc` at last to be more precise

Comment: FYI: Lookbehind is now supported by FF (v78)

Comment: @Mandy8055 this works. You can add a solution so I can close the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
.*id_token=(.*?)&.*
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`.*`** - **Greedily** matches everything before `id_token=`.
- **`id_token=`** - Matches `id_token=` literally.
- **`(.*?)`** - Represents a capturing group matching everything before `&`.
- **`.*`** - Matches everything after `&` greedily.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

#### Regex Demo